# ¿Como puedo cambiar el idioma de mi pagina en Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

tengo un proyecto en laravel, lo que deseo es cambiar la carpeta lang a la que accede al hacer click sobre el lenguaje que quiero seleccionar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esta lista, quiero que al hacer click sobre la bandera cambie el lang pero he intentado de distintas maneras

`App::setLocale('es'); 
session()->put('locale', 'es');`

y no funciona mi pagina sigue extrayendo la informacion del arreglo de idiomas **en**

¿alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Comment: Hice un video detallado sobre el uso de varios idiomas en Laravel, el material esta en youtube aqui adjunto el link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0e-LRU0_-0Y&t=130s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero debes asegurarte que estas usando la siguiente sintaxis.

```
echo __('messages.welcome');

echo __('I love programming.');
```

Si usas blade como motor de tempalte

```
{{ __('messages.welcome') }}

@lang('messages.welcome')
```

Finalmente revisa bien el path de tus traducciones.

**resources/lang/vendor/{package}/{locale}**

Este es un ejemplo muy basico para hacer el cambio de traducción

```
Route::get('welcome/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);

    //
});
```